# C++ some variable issue with grpc

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, grpc

I have grpc service, that wraps some third library functions. The class of called library is `T_Upt`. When `_upt->GetState` is being called from `Status TerminalService::GetState` the `state` is **empty**. If I move the `_upt->GetState` call to constructor

```
TerminalService::TerminalService(): _upt(std::make_unique<T_Upt>())
{
    T_UptState state{};
    _upt->GetState(&state);
    std::cout << state.cbTerminalID << std::endl;
}
```

then everything is fine. Like why? I have tried different approaches using `std::move`, or `T_Upt*` instead, nothing works. Not sure if it's important, but the library is single threaded, but it shouldn't be a problem since I'm not using the `RegisterAsyncGenericService`.

full code below

service.h

```
class TerminalService final : public TerminalGrpcService::Service
{
public:
    TerminalService();

    Status Cancel(ServerContext* context, const CancelRequest* request, CancelReply* response) override;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T_Upt> _upt;
};
```

service.cpp

```
TerminalService::TerminalService(): _upt(std::make_unique<T_Upt>())
{
}

Status TerminalService::GetState(ServerContext* context, const ::GetStateRequest* request,
    GetStateReplay* response)
{
    T_UptState state{};
    const bool result = this->_upt->GetState(&state);

    response->set_result(result);
    response->set_terminalid(std::string(state.cbTerminalID));

    return Status::OK;
}
```

main

```
int main()
{
    const std::string address("127.0.0.1:1111");
    TerminalService service;
    ServerBuilder builder;

    builder.AddListeningPort(address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on port: " << address << std::endl;
    server->Wait();
}
```

Update: using static(global variable) didn't helped either, I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem, there was some specific method `bSetEcrMode` in library that made everything work.